# Schedule a Azure devops release in multiple timings

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, azure-devops-rest-api

I am able to schedule the release using Rest API call . Is there any way to Queue it to run Multiple times.THe code i tried is given below.

```
$timinglist=@(1:30,2:30,3:30)

foreach($time in $timinglist)
 {
    $PATtoken= 'PAT'
    Write-Host "Initialize Autnetication COntext" -ForegroundColor DarkBlue
    $token = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($PATtoken)"))
    $header=@{authorization= "Basic $token" }

    $defurl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/Organization/Project/_apis/release/definitions/13?api-version=5.1" 


   $definition = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $defurl -Method Get -Headers $header
   $hour=$time.Split(":")[0]
   $minute=$time.Split(":")[1]

   $hash = @(
   @{ 
      triggerType="schedule";
      schedule = @{"daysToRelease"="31";"timeZoneId"="India Standard Time";"startHours"=$hour;"startMinutes"=$minute}
   })
   $definition.triggers = $hash     

   $json = @($definition) | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99 

   $updatedef = Invoke-RestMethod  -Uri $defurl  -Method Put -Body $json -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
   Write-Host ($updatedef.triggers | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 99)
}
```

My objective is to queue a release at 1:30 2:30 and 3:30 . But with the above code it is running only at 3:30 and other two are not happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are overriding the `triggers` property every time you send the request.
So the last value wins over the old ones.

`triggers` property is an array of `BuildTrigger`, you don't need to execute 3 request, just one!
[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/update%20definition?view=vsts-rest-tfs-4.1#buildtrigger) is the `triggers` documentation.

**EDIT:**

I am not a powershell wizard but you should create an array of `BuildTrigger` object like this:

```
$hash = @(
   @{ 
      triggerType="schedule";
      schedule = @{"daysToRelease"="31";"timeZoneId"="India Standard Time";"startHours"=$hour1;"startMinutes"=$minute1}
   },
   @{ 
      triggerType="schedule";
      schedule = @{"daysToRelease"="31";"timeZoneId"="India Standard Time";"startHours"=$hour2;"startMinutes"=$minute2}
   },
   @{ 
      triggerType="schedule";
      schedule = @{"daysToRelease"="31";"timeZoneId"="India Standard Time";"startHours"=$hour3;"startMinutes"=$minute3}
   }
   )
```

Comment: But how to specify that array in the above powershell script

Comment: This is another question, but I tried to answer as well as I can. I edited the answer adding the array creation.

Comment: Added a new question please check whether you also came through it 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59087121/schedule-a-azure-devops-release-in-multiple-timing-by-passing-different-variable